# Heroku need help handling bloat in database and vacuuming

Tags: laravel, heroku, psql

Today, I started getting timeout errors from heroku. I eventually ran this ...

```
heroku pg:diagnose -a myapp
```

and got ...

```
RED: Bloat
Type   Object                                         Bloat  Waste
─────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────  ───────
table  public.files                                   776    1326 MB
index  public.files::files__lft__rgt_parent_id_index  63     106 MB
RED: Hit Rate
Name                    Ratio
──────────────────────  ──────────────────
overall cache hit rate  0.8246404842342929
public.files            0.8508127886460272
```

I ran the VACUUM command and it did nothing to address the bloat. How do I address this?

Comment: How have you determined that a couple hundred MB of bloat is the cause for your timeouts?

Comment: No. I have no idea how to make that determination. I am just clawing around in the dark.

Comment: You need to identify where the bottleneck is - it might be slow application code, or it could be a very slow database query, or you could be exhausting your dyno memory. Look at the metrics tab heroku provides - see if your dyno load spikes, or if memory spikes. There are also addons that help monitor performance - NewRelic is popular and Librato is also good. It is unlikely to be bloat. You cache hit rate is a bit low which can slow down queries somewhat - a larger db plan would improve your cache hit rate. But the cache hit rate probably not the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer. For anyone else facing the same issue, he might try the following for vacuum:

```
    VACUUM (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, FULL) your-table-name;
```